# How do I print adjacent elements that have maximum differences if there are two max differences in the array

Tags: arrays, c, difference

I made a program where I've inputted an array of n elements and I'm trying to find the differences of two adjacent elements in the array. After I find the max difference of two numbers I'm supposed to print those two array elements.

I've successfully found the max difference of an array if there's only one pair of adjacent elements. The problem is what if I'm given a test case where there are two pairs of elements that have the same maximum difference value? I'm wondering how do I print those two pairs of numbers since my code only prints out the first two adjacent elements and not the rest

Sample input:

```
10
-57 -25 -11 -6 3 9 23 45 68 100
```

What's the output should be:

```
-57 -25 68 100
```

But my program is only printing -57 and -25 and ignores the other pair.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n,i,j,a[10000],temp,count=0;
    int diff = a[1]-a[0];
    
    scanf("%d",&n);
    getchar();
    
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        getchar();  
    }
    
    for(i=0; i<n-1; i++){
        for(j=0; j<n-i-1; j++){
            if(a[j] > a[j+1]){
                temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j+1];
                a[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<n-1; i++){
        if(a[i+1]-a[i] > diff){
            diff = a[i+1]-a[i]; 
            count++;
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<count; i++){
        printf("%d %d ",a[i],a[i+1]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You do not remember the indexes.
2. You should check if the difference is greater **or equal**.

```
int indexes[n];

for(i=0; i<n-1; i++){
    if(a[i+1]-a[i] >= diff){
        diff = a[i+1]-a[i]; 
        indexes[count] = i;
        count++;
    }
}

printf("%d\n", count);
for(i=0; i<count; i++){
    printf("%d %d ",a[indexes[i]],a[indexes[i]+1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need another array to keep track of the previous (equal) maximums

```
int delta = -1;
for (index = 0; index < n - 1; index++) {
    int delta = abs(a[index] - a[index + 1]);
    if (delta > maximum) {
        // new maximum, reset track array
    } else {
        if (delta == maximum) {
            // repeated maximum, add to track array
        } else {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
}
```